# Show additional record information in a continuous form

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am using a continuous form to show quarterly payment dates.

```
| Name | Q1_Paid | Q2_Paid | Q3_Paid | Q4_Paid |
```

I would like to have the ability to add comments to a payment, btu I do not want the comments to show all the time (cleaner form).  I would like to add a button for each row that works similar to a tree button, that shows a row with the comments.

```
|+ Name | Q1_Paid | Q2_Paid | Q3_Paid | Q4_Paid |
|       | Q1_Note | Q2_Note | Q3_Note | Q4_Note |
```

I was able to add a '+' button to the row, and coded it to reformat the form to show the additional row, however it shows it for all records, not just for the record I want to see the additional information.

Is there a way show an additional 'row' of information for a single record in a continuous form?  If not, is there a way to emulate this function?  I reviewed information for the tree function, but it does not appear to be available in access anymore, and I don't believe it would do what I wanted it to do anyway.

Comment: AFAIK, No and No. Could have notes entered in a popup form. Record on primary form would have to first be committed to table.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way show an additional 'row' of information for a single
> record in a continuous form?

Not in-line, but this is often done in the form header or footer.